# Notepad++: Copy text portion value and replace other text portion with this value

Tags: regex, variables, search, replace, notepad++

Skip first paragraph if you just want to see the problem and offer quick solution, first paragraph is just background on me trying to get my head around this.

Been using RegEx in NP++ for a while, but one thing I can't quite get my head around is how one stores and utilises "variables" using it. I've been trying to understand it for a while, and this isn't the first time I've run into this issue, but before now, I've always eventually given up and resorted to some kind of workaround to avoid using these things. By variables I mean the way one can use stuff like \1 \2 etc to store and replace values. I've been reading numerous SO threads but I just can't seem to get it. So I was hoping someone could give me a solution to this problem, plus an explanation of what the RegEx is doing/how it's functioning, so I can resolve this issue and maybe finally get my head around using these things in general.

So I have a file, specifically my iTunes Library XML file, and I want to replace the value of one field with the value of another. For example, I have:

```
        <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2040-02-05T21:28:16Z</date>
        <key>Release Date</key><date>2015-08-22T17:08:10Z</date>
```

And I want to have:

```
        <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-08-22T17:08:10Z</date>
        <key>Release Date</key><date>2015-08-22T17:08:10Z</date>
```

That is, replace the value of "Play Date UTC" with the value of "Release Date" for multiple items through the file.

I figure the way to do this is, in pseduo-RegEx, something like:

Search:

```
[Variable 1=]<key>Play Date UTC</key><date>[/Variable 1]
[Variable 2=]{Wildcard}[/Variable 2]
[Variable 3=]</date>{newline}<key>Release Date</key><date>[/Variable 3]
[Variable 4=]2015-08-22T17:08:10Z[/Variable 4]
[Variable 5=]</date>[/Variable 5]
```

Replace:

```
[Variable 1][Variable 4][Variable 3][Variable 4][Variable 5]
```

If that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why dont you copy the value which you want to replace and just write regex for the pattern where you want the value to be replaced? some thing like: `match : (<key>Release Date<\/key><date>)[^<](<\/date>) and replace with : $12015-08-22T17:08:10Z$2`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

Find what: `(<key>Play Date UTC</key><date>)[^<]+(</date>\s+<key>Release Date</key><date>([^>]+)</date>)`
Replace with: `$1$3$2`

**Explanation:**

```
(                                   : begin group 1
  <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>    : literally
)                                   : end group 2
[^<]+                               : every thing that is not <
(                                   : begin group 2
  </date>                           : literally
  \s+                               : 1 or more space char (including linebreak)
  <key>Release Date</key><date>     : literally
  ([^>]+)                           : group 3, every thing that is not < (ie the date)
  </date>                           : literally
)                                   : end group 2
```